# Homemade share buttons using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, share

**SOLUTION**

Remove comments in scripts... The comments made the remaining script part of the comments.

**Question**

I managed to create a jQuery script to share individual pages to some socialmedias. The reason for this is to get less cookies as some share button providers use cookies and these cookies might conflict with the new GDPR.

The code below works as a charm in a jsfiddle (except the email part), but as I upload the code to my website the icons show up but does not work! There comes no pop-up window or other things.

Can someome please give my code below a quick look to see what I do wrong?

Below code is also to be found in this working jsfiddle:
**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqfyot42/65/)**

***HTML***

```
<div id="share-buttons">
  <span class="social-share facebook" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></span>
  <span class="social-share twitter" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></span>
  <span style="cursor: pointer;"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.print()"><img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/print.png" alt="Print" /></a></span>
  <span class="social-share email" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/email.png" alt="Email" /></span>
</div>
```

***jQuery/Javascript***

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
setShareLinks();

function socialWindow(url) {
  var left = (screen.width - 570) / 2;
  var top = (screen.height - 570) / 2;
  var params = "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=570,height=570,top=" + top + ",left=" + left;
  // params = "";
  window.open(url,"NewWindow",params);
}

function setShareLinks() {
  var pageUrl = encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
  var tweet = encodeURIComponent($("meta[property='og:description']").attr("content"));

  $(".social-share.facebook").on("click", function() {
    url = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + pageUrl;
    socialWindow(url);
  });

  $(".social-share.twitter").on("click", function() {
    url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" + pageUrl + "&text=" + tweet;
    socialWindow(url);
  });

  $(".social-share.email").on("click", function() {
    url = "mailto:?Subject=" + tweet + "&amp;Body=" + pageUrl;
    socialWindow(url);
  });

}
});
</script>
```

*Share buttons are "borrowed" from simplesharebuttons.com*

Comment: `pageurl` should be `pageUrl` - is that a typo?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include jquery? Or your code executes before the page is loaded and the buttons are created - use document ready handler for that, with jquery that means putting your code in `$(function() { ... })`.

Comment: @Simon : maybe the popup don't open because they are blocked by a popup-blocker. You can try to debug and do a console.log(url) in your function socialWindow() to be sure if she is called when you click on the twitter/facebook icons...Are the print and mail icons work ? If no, then it's maybe another problem than the popup-blocker ? If you can give us the url of your website (if possible), will help us to help you ;-)

Comment: Press F12 in your browser and look for console tab. The error is there.

Comment: @TheUknown Yes that is a typpo. But thank you. I didn't see that one :)

Comment: @riv I did include jQuery but I do that with the metatags etc. I do put my code into function blocks or do you mean another way?

Comment: @Pierre Yes that was also my first thought but it isn't that :( 
I'm doing a make over of the website at the moment so please bear in mind all the faults and some bad code ;) 
[Link to website](http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/)

Comment: @Emeeus Yes it comes with a fault but it seems not to be something that has something to do with this :(

Comment: @SimonJensen what is the error message displayed in the console ?

Comment: @Pierre Copy/paste: ReferenceError: stLight is not defined[Learn More] www.stutteri-volstrup.dk:6:1
<anonymous>
http://www.stutteri-volstrup.dk/:6:1
SyntaxError: missing } after function body[Learn More] www.stutteri-volstrup.dk:6:992 note: { opened at line 6, column 43www.stutteri-volstrup.dk:6:43. This seems not have anything to do with my problem.

Comment: @SimonJensen for me stLight can be an error of your share button, i remember having such problem with sharethis some time ago.  There is a conflict with someone else, another javascript or maybe a chrome extension...Can you try to load in Chrome's incognito mode, and tell us if the problem is always here ?

Comment: And i hope you launch setShareLinks() after jquery is loaded, ie with  $( document ).ready(function() { setShareLinks() });

Comment: I'm one of the few who doesn't have Chrome. I have tested in Firefox, Edge, IE and Safari. I believe Incognito is the same as "Privacy". Same problem.

I did built this script in a jsfiddle for easy testing and it works so no I doesn't launch setShareLinks() after jQuery is loaded....?

Comment: Can you do  $( document ).ready(function() { setShareLinks(); }) in your website and tell us if it works better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script (on the website) was messed up with comments. Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setShareLinks();

function socialWindow(url) {
    var left = (screen.width - 570) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - 570) / 2;
    var params = "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=570,height=570,top=" + top + ",left=" + left;
    window.open(url, "NewWindow", params);
}

function setShareLinks() {
    var pageUrl = encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
    var tweet = encodeURIComponent($("meta[property='og:description']").attr("content"));
    $(".social-share.facebook").on("click", function() {
        url = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + pageUrl;
        socialWindow(url);
    });
    $(".social-share.twitter").on("click", function() {
        url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" + pageUrl + "&text=" + tweet;
        socialWindow(url);
    });
    $(".social-share.email").on("click", function() {
        url = "mailto:?Subject=" + tweet + "&amp;Body=" + pageurl;
        socialWindow(url);
    });
}

});
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually it was the comments that hided the rest of the script. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several causes to your problem :

- you don't launch your main function after jquery loads...in your sample code, you don't have $( document ).ready(function() { setShareLinks() }) ...Yes JSFiddle works, but jsfiddle automatically puts your JS code in window.onload() function...
- simplesharebuttons.com is maybe using sharethis API, that's why you have "stLight is not defined" error in your Chrome console.
- sometimes with such share/tracking codes you have incompatibilites with other JS codes, and chrome extension enabling incognito mode...try to disable all these extension, or relaunch your website in Chrome incognito mode, or use a fresh browser (like a portable browser)
- and according the fact you code your window.open, the popups can be blocked by the browser (the current rule in the browsers being "if the popup isn't opened by a direct user action, then it's blocked")

Comment: Thank you Pierre. I have updated the code in my question to include `$( document ).ready(function() { setShareLinks() })`. I have disabled all API's and they are removed from site. I have tried in Chrome Incognitomode now with the same results as the other browsers. I have no popupblockers installed on this PC. Please suggest another way to avoid popupblockers. Using CSS or another codetrick?

Comment: I don't remember if you put console.log(url) in your socialWindow() function ? 
If the url is then written in Chrome console, then your code launchs correctly socialWindow function. In this case, if the popup doesn't open, that's sure it's the window.open that doesn't work...it's a way for debugging...please put console.log(url)  and tell me what is the result...

Comment: I found the problem. It was the comments i added in the script. In my editor i set on lines. The browser puts some of the scripts on ONE line, there fore `//` will affect later of the page. I really didn't thought about that. Thank you very much for your help.
You said in your answer that using `window.open` could be blocked by popupblockers. Do you have another option you can suggest?

Comment: Your popups shouldn't be blocked. They are currently opened by a direct user action. If i'm not wrong, the current rule in the browsers is "if the popup isn't opened by a direct user action, then it's blocked". So it should be ok for your current use case

Comment: thanks @SimonJensen . Was a pleasure to help you, even if finally you found yourself the problem ;-)